# 'Get' logic when using automapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, automapper

This is my Entity:

```
public class CouponEntity
{
    public int CouponId { get; set; }
    public int CompanyNumber { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }

    public string CompanySlug
    {
        get
        {
            return COMMONCONSTANTS.URL_COMPANY + "/" + this.CompanyNumber;
        }
    }
}
```

And the following is my DTO:

```
public class CouponDto
{    
    [DataMember]
    public string CompanySlug { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

My question is: does using `Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<CouponEntity>, IEnumerable<CouponDto>>(lstProducts)` greatly affect performance?

I got the following from the AutoMapper creator somewhere on the Internet:

> DTO is a strict projection of the data model. No business logic in
>   mapping 99% "Auto" - restrict customization to minimum Prefer LINQ
>   projection

So, is this what should be avoided? Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this scenario, using AutoMapper is unlikely to have a noticeable impact on performance.
Creating the map, Mapper.CreateMap(), *does* tend to have an impact on performance, so be sure that you only call CreateMap() once when the application starts.